# AngularJS form validation with MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs

I'm building a single page web application. This has many different forms on it that will require validation. I'm not using any of the Razor form validation, or views. Instead everything is held in Angular templates.

I get my data from the server using Web Api calls, including lists of form elements as many of the forms are dynamic.

I would prefer that my models hold all of the validation. I know I could duplicate this validation onto my angular templates for forms that aren't dynamic but this means that the validation has to be maintained in two places - I would rather keep it in one place, on my model, so that client and server validation are inline with each other.

What would be the best way to extract the validation on my model and use it on the front end?

Comment: I've looked into this myself before. The bottomline is that the out of the box validation code is stored in very different languages. It seems to be too much work to convert either one into the other. A tool would likely be the best option. I would be willing to participate in an effort to create a tool for this. I am curious to see what answers do you get.

Comment: Is it possible to get the validation attributes from a model?

Comment: You might want to look into Breeze for inspiration here.  http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/validation

Comment: I don't think this question is too broad, it just may not have an answer at this point.

Comment: You can use [ngval](https://github.com/alisabzevari/ngval) that brings data annotations to client side as angularjs validators.

Comment: That sounds great, I'll have to take a look at that.